# int cant be converted into resultSet

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

Hi all the code works without the result set but I need it included for me to add it to the result set. Is there any way I can do it in the one method?
This code is used to update user details in my java program. I use the resultset to get user details.

```
public User editUserDetails(int userID ,String email, String password, String fName, String lName, String bio, String image) {

    boolean found = false;
    Connection c = DBHelperClass.getConnection();
    String query = "UPDATE user SET email= ? , password= ?,fName= ?,lName= ?,bio= ?,image=? WHERE userID= ?";

    if (c != null) {
        try {
            PreparedStatement inserter = c.prepareStatement(query);
            inserter.setString(1, email);
            inserter.setString(2, password);
            inserter.setString(3, fName);
            inserter.setString(4, lName);
            inserter.setString(5, bio);
            inserter.setString(6, image);
            inserter.setInt(7, userID);

            System.out.println("Update user: " + query);
            ResultSet resultSet = inserter.executeUpdate();
            inserter.executeUpdate();
            inserter.close();

            while (resultSet.next()) {
                this.setUserID(resultSet.getInt("userID"));
                this.email = resultSet.getString("email");
                this.setPassword(resultSet.getString("password"));
                this.type=resultSet.getString("type");
                this.fName=resultSet.getString("fName");
                this.lName=resultSet.getString("lName");
                found = true;

            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(User.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
    return this;
}
```

error is on line:
ResultSet resultSet = inserter.executeUpdate();

error is :int can not be converted to ResultSet

Comment: In which line you are facing problem

Comment: This line                 ResultSet resultSet = inserter.executeUpdate();

Comment: Actually, what is the problem, I couldn't understand. Can you be more clear a bit?

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: `executeUpdate()` does not return a `ResultSet`. If you want to retrieve data from the database, you will need a SELECT-statement executed with `executeQuery()` which does return a resultSet. However I don't understand why you want to retrieve a `ResultSet` within an update method.

Comment: Ok thank you I will change the code.

Answer (score 1):

You construct the query using the string 'query' which is an update statement, an update is like an insert, it does not return a result set.

The specification of ExecuteUpdate is:

> "Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, which
>   must be an SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statement, such as
>   INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE; or an SQL statement that returns nothing,
>   such as a DDL statement."

(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

You need to change your code to 
inserter.executeQuery();
but you will also need to change the actual query to a select statement or any statement that returns something.

Hope this helps